# Using wrong syntax in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, syntax

```
$screenWidth = $(document).width();
      if ($screenWidth < 980) {
        document.getElementsById("show-menu").removeAttribute("checked");
        alert($screenWidth);
      }
```

Apparently, the syntax I'm using here isn't correct. Where is the mistake?

Comment: getElementById, not elements. ids should be unique so getting multiples doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: it doesnt remove the attribute checked. [link](http://alphafotograf.de/index.php/template-test)

Comment: You should have seen "not a function" in your javascript console and it would have pointed to this line.

Comment: Did you even tried to look at the code? Did you tried something before posting?

Comment: yes, of course i did

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7j1sur35/

Comment: @SimonMathewson In that case, note that the order of the elements matters. Being last, the `<input>` won't yet exist when the `<script>` is trying to find it. Either swap their order (http://jsfiddle.net/7j1sur35/1/) or have the script use an event to wait (http://jsfiddle.net/7j1sur35/3/).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById`, you have an extra `s`

also since you're using jquery you could do:

```
$('#show-menu').removeAttr('checked');
```